# Derivative of the divergence of a vector field with respect to the vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Very simply, I am trying to solve the following function in a 3D space:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial F}(\nabla\cdot F)
$$
where $F$ is a vector field.  I THINK this should be zero based on physical reasoning, but every attempt to solve it rigorously has failed.

Approach 1:

Use a vector identity and rotational invariance, and solve in one dimension.
Given
$$
\nabla(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})=(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A})
$$
I came out to a result that made little sense (though I think I see where I made the error while invoking rotational invariance):
$$
=2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\cdot F\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial F}
$$
clearly recovering an operator as a result doesn't work physically.

Approach 2:

Again, work in one dimension and play some chain rule games
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial F}(\nabla\cdot F)=\frac{\partial\left(\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial F}=\frac{\partial^2F_x}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial F}
$$
but again, here I get lost.

Approach 3:
Invoke Gauss' law, which gets the closest ultimately:
$$
\int_v \frac{\partial}{\partial F}(\nabla\cdot F)dv=\int_{dv}\mathbf{\hat{n}}\cdot dS
$$
which is surface area.  So we arrive that the integral of this function is equal to the surface area of the bounding volume.  What can we say about a function if its integral is a constant?

Any help or even a general direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but formally, if you differentiate a linear functional with respect to the variable you will get the functional back?

Comment: I don't understand either, but note that : 1. it makes no sense a priori to talk about the gradient of a vector field and 2. if the derivative of a map vanishes everywhere, then it is constant (if the domain of definition is connected, which seems to be the case here)

Comment: My apologies, the title should read "derivative of the DIVERGENCE of a function with respect to the function"

Comment: What do you mean by "derivative with respect to a function"?

Comment: It was erroneous nomenclature on my part--5pm has restated it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more precise to say: the derivative of the divergence of a vector field with respect to that field. (You say "function" but then $F$ turns out to be a vector field.) In symbols, it could be expressed as $D_F (\nabla \cdot F)$ although notation varies. It helps to write fields in derivative notation, 
$$F=\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 
\tag1$$ 
where $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are scalar functions, the components of the field. Then the divergence of $F$ is expressed by 
$$\nabla \cdot F=\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial f_i }{\partial x_i} 
\tag2$$
The derivative of (2) with respect to the vector field (1) comes out as the double sum
$$D_F(\nabla \cdot F)=\sum_{i=1}^3 f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial f_j }{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i,j=1}^3 f_i \frac{\partial^2 f_j }{\partial x_i\partial x_j}
\tag3$$
The expression (3) is not zero in general. For example, take $f_i=x_i^2$ for $i=1,2,3$: then the sum (3) evaluates to $2(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$.

Comment: This certainly helps, but can you please elaborate on (1) a bit?  I have never encountered this--I found an article on Leibniz notation for vector fields; is this the same thing?

Comment: @AndyK. Probably [this article](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/LeibnizNotationForVectorFields.html). Yes, this is the notation I use in (1). It looks odd at first, but helps in computations because it tells exactly what the field does to functions. In differential geometry, vector fields are often **defined** via their action on functions, as linear functional that  satisfy the Leibniz rule.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you (and that was indeed the article).  My reasoning that it should be zero was predicated on a false assumption made before the statement of the problem (but that is a physics issue, not a maths one).

Comment: The link for the PlanetMath is now dead, use [this one](http://planetmath.org/leibniznotationforvectorfields) instead.